# Show a property of a vector space axiom equivalent to another property

Tags: linear-algebra

Will try to prove additive inverse axiom is equivalent to saying $0v = 0$ for all $v \in V.$

Given $v+ w = 0$ for all $v$ and some $w \in V$, we have $w = -v$ and $v+ w = -v + v = -1v + 1v = (-1 + 1)v = 0v = 0$.

In the other direction, $0 =  v – v = 0v$. Let $w = -v$. Then $0 = 0v = w + v$.

Checking if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v+ (-v) = 0 \iff v\cdot 1 + v \cdot (-1) =0 ^ * \iff v(1+(-1)) = 0 \iff v\cdot 0 = 0$

$^*$Prove this separately.

Comment: This proof suffers from the same problems as the proof posted by the OP. Namely, you've assumed $-1v=-v$ (which is true). However, $-1v=-v$ is *not* an axiom. It needs to be proven.

Answer (score 0):

When showing that $0v=0$, you've assumed $-1v=-v$. This isn't an axiom and it needs to be proven before using this (correct) fact.

Here's a proof using just the axioms:

Let $V$ be a vector space and $v \in V$. We have $0v+0v=(0+0)v=0v$ (using the axiom that $(s+t)v=sv+tv$ for vectors $v$ and scalars $s,t$). But $0v$ is an element of $V$, so it must have an (additive) inverse: $-(0v)$. Add this to our previous equation: $(0v+0v)+(-0v)=0v+(-0v)$. Using associativity, $0v+(0v+(-(0v)))=0$ and so $0v+0=0$ and so $0v=0$ (here we've used the axiom which says $0$ is an additive identity several times).

Now for the other direction, your proof again has a problem of assuming too much. You've assumed that $-v$ exists while showing that it exists!

Instead, assume that $0v=0$. Then $v+(-1v) = 1v+(-1v)=(1-1)v=0v=0$. Here I've used the axioms: $1v=v$, $(r+s)v=rv+sv$ and our assumption that $0v=0$.

Likewise, $(-1v)+v=(-1v)+1v=(-1+1)v=0v=0$. Therefore, $w+v=v+w=0$ when $w=-1v$. This shows that $v$ has an additive inverse, namely $-1v$. If we also showed that when an additive inverse exists it is unique (i.e. there can be only one), then we would have $-1v=-v$. :)

Comment: Sorry I already accepted the other question. Didn't see yours coming. I am using Axler's book and the lemma $-1v = -v$ is proven in the text. Does that make the proof in OP correct, though?  I am more interested in the correct usage of things like "let -v = w", quantifiers and stuff like that. That's where I tend to make mistakes. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you are asked to prove one axiom is equivalent to some other statement, you need to be very careful which lemmas you use. You don't want to end up assuming what you're proving. In your case, showing that the existence of inverses implies that $0v=0$, using that lemma is fine. On the other hand, showing that $0v=0$ implies the existence of inverses, using the lemma probably isn't ok unless that lemma is proven without assuming the inverse axiom (which I'm betting it does). In the end, if you are asked to prove one axiom is equivalent to another, the safest route is to avoid using an lemmas.